# Amazon Sagemaker - Create USA map by States using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I been trying creating USA map in Amazon Sagemaker Jupyter notebook instance, I have used the code

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dff = pd.read_excel("fold/map_data.xlsx",engine='openpyxl')

# Strip out white spaces

dff.columns = dff.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())

# Keep only Required cloumns,

dff=dff[['week_end','state','state_code','item','sales']]

# Filter the data and rename

dff=dff[(dff['week_end']=='12-12-2022') & (dff['item']=='Resd')] 
dff.rename({'sales':'Sales Price ($)'},axis=1, inplace=True)

fig = px.choropleth(dff,
                    locations='state_code', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    scope="usa",
                    color='Sales Price ($)',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis_r", 
                    
                    )
fig.show()
```

Data used

[image]

No Map is showing up,not even outline or any error. When I searched in Browser console I am getting warning "**Default Kernel not found**"

What am I missing here? Please help me understand. Is there any additional steps to be done since I am running inside Sagemaker?

Comment: To reproduce your problem, can you share a sample or website source of xlsx data?

Comment: Added Sample Data

Comment: What type of conda env are you using? What is your version of sagemaker?

Comment: 3.6.13 | packaged by conda-forge | 
[GCC 9.3.0]

Comment: Can you try using the 'conda_python3' kernel? Your code works correctly for me. If it works for you too, I will write an extended answer to explain it better.

Comment: I tried it with conda_python3, still the same :(